# hide/show search layout on listview scroll

Tags: android, listview

i have made a search layout above listview and i want to hide/show this search layout on listview scroll like on scrolling the facebook newsfeed show/hide the search bar on the top of news feed i have attached the my screenshot please see the screen shot and guide me about this. Thanks

[screen shot of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3owM.png)

here is my listview scroll listener

in this i have tried but this is not what i want. i want something like facbook newsfeed as i told earlier.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    if (userScrolled && firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount+1 == totalItemCount+1) {

        userScrolled = false;
        if (nextPage)
            updateListView();
    }
}
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    int position = bussinesList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View v = bussinesList.getChildAt(0);
    int offset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

    if (mPosition < position || (mPosition == position && mOffset < offset)){
        // Scrolled up
        searchlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else {
        // Scrolled down
        searchlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
        userScrolled = true;
        //linearlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```